# Parsing a xml file in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I have a xml file :

```
<root>
    <book
         name="Science1"
         author="XYZ1">
    </book>
    <book
         name="Science2"
         author="XYZ2">
    </book>
</root>
```

I want to get the value of name and author. Java code to parse the above :

```
 Document doc = null;

    try {

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmldata);//newfile
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl1.item(i);

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_AUTHOR,parser.getValue(e, KEY_AUTHOR));
        Log.d("Debug","Value + " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME) + " " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AUTHOR));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I am missing here, as when I print the tag value, I don't get any value.

Please suggest / help how can I read this format ? If this format has any other dependency like schema / DTD to be provided, let me know, as I am totally unaware of the correct flow. Please suggest me some site as well where I can validate my xml file as well.

Comment: try `parser.getAttribute("key")` instead of  `getValue` .

Comment: `org.w3c.dom.Element.getAttribute(String name)`  is a method of `Element` class. Show your import statements.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I tried on the same parser, then checked and got the answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the xml-File in this format:

```
<root>
    <book name="Science1"
         author="XYZ1"/>
    <book name="Science2"
         author="XYZ2" />
</root>
```

And than for your for-loop:

```
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nl1.getLength(); temp++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Node nNode = nl1.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            map.put(KEY_NAME, eElement.getAttribute("name"));
            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, eElement.getAttribute("author"));
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I did not changed the xml, but this still worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. I wasn´t sure if it would work with yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

Man, just read this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html